# I am new to protractor.According to my company policies i cannot use xpath I am struggling with the following code. I really appreciate your response

Tags: css, css-selectors, ui-automation

We have a small AngularJs application and I want to write some automation test scripts leveraging the current cucumber-protractor-typescript framework. I am concerned about writing reliable locators being new to Angular applications.

Following is the example HTML code. Here I want to write a locator for a drop down icon:

```
<span class="mat-expansion-indicator ng-tns-c22-597 ng-trigger ng-trigger-indicatorRotate ng-star-inserted" style="transform: rotate(1800deg);"></span>
```

Here is my xpath locator:

```
expandedBrandIcon = element(by.xpath("//h2[contains(text(),'Brand')]/ancestor::mat-expansion-panel-header//span[contains(@style,'180deg')]
```

Comment: Please take the [tour] and learn [ask].

Comment: You forgot to post your code and what you have completed so far in terms of this task.

Comment: I am trying to attach an image. How you tell me how can I do that

Comment: Don't add code in images. Instead add a code snippet in the question

Comment: <span class="mat-expansion-indicator ng-tns-c22-597 ng-trigger ng-trigger-indicatorRotate ng-star-inserted" style="transform: rotate(1800deg);"></span>

Comment: But I cannot use xpath as per my company standards. Is there any possiblitly for CSS

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to select an element based on the containing text as you did with XPath, pure CSS cannot do that. Try this for CSS selector (best I can do with the HTML you provided):

```
div.ng-star-inserted span.mat-expansion-indicator[style='180deg']
```